#  Is it possible to find radical solution of $\sin(5\beta)+\sin(\beta)=1$  and finding radical approximation of $\pi$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, pi

[image]

ABCD is a unit square. There are 2 circles in picture. The center of one is A and passing from F. The center of another is D and passing from C.
If $\alpha=2\beta$ then
I got the following results

$|AF|=x$

$\cos(2\beta)=\frac{1}{x}$

and from isoscale triangle (ADG): 
$\sin(3\beta)=\frac{x}{2}$

$\sin(3\beta)\cos(2\beta)=\frac{1}{2}$

$\sin(5\beta)+\sin(\beta)=1$

$\sin(\beta)=P$

my first question: Is it possible to find a solution of P via radicals?

Second question:
During my drawing the figure that Area of (CGH region) is equal about Area of (HBF region) (just I noticed with  geometrical drawing tool).I do not claim that they are equal Because I know very well that it is impossible to [Squaring a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle).(more info is in Wiki link)

I try to find approximation of $\pi$ in radicals via the figure if possible.
Note:If you know interesting $\pi$ approximations via Squaring a circle, I would like to know them.
Thanks for advices and answers

EDIT:

I asked the question to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin5x%2bsinx=1). I got fifth degree polinom with real coefficients.

$\sin(5\beta)+\sin(\beta)=1$

$\sin^5(\beta)+5\sin(\beta)\cos^4(\beta)-10\sin^3(\beta)\cos^2(\beta)+\sin(\beta)=1$

$\sin^5(\beta)+5\sin(\beta)(1-\sin^2(\beta))^2-10\sin^3(\beta)(1-\sin^2(\beta))+\sin(\beta)=1$

$\sin(\beta)=P$

$16P^5-20P^3+6P=1$

Really $P=\sin(\pi /6)=\frac{1}{2}$ is a solution of the polinom.

All roots are in [the link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16x%5E5-20x%5E3%2b6x-1=0). What a pity that wolfram did not offer me radical solutions for [4 degree polinom](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8x%5E4%2b4x%5E3-8x%5E2-4x%2b1=0) either. I will check other tools to find radical solutions of the roots.
For my second question  UPDATE:

I decided to see if really Areas are about eqaul to each other.

the  root is for my first drawing: I will take the solution about $P\approx0.188286$ from wolfram solution.

$\sin(\beta)\approx0.188286$

$\beta\approx0.189416$

$|AF|=x$

$\cos(2\beta)=\frac{1}{x}$

$x=\frac{1}{\cos(2\beta)}\approx1.076314$

Area of (CGH region)=  ([wiki link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%28%28%280.189416/2%29*%281.076314%29%5E2%29%2bsqrt%28%281.076314%5E2%29-1%29/2%20%2b%28sin%20%286%280.189416%29%29%29/2%2b%28%5Cpi/4-3*0.189416%29%29%29%29))
[image]

Area of (HBF region)=  ([Wiki Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%280.189416%29*%281.076314%29%5E2%29-%28sqrt%28%281.076314%5E2%29-1%29/2%20))
[image]

RESULT: I wonder if I use more digits of the root what Areas will be.
it seems that numerical solution of areas are very near each other.
I will update if I find radical solution of polinom and I will update if I find some other results.
Your helps will be appreciated very much to analyze the results.

Thanks a lot to Chris K. Caldwel for his contribution.
I drew the solution he offered .
[image]

Comment: To answer your first question: one solution to $\sin(5\beta)+\sin(\beta)=1$ is $\pi/6$, so since $sin(5\beta)$ can be written as fifth degree polynomial in terms of $\sin\beta$, the remaining four solutions to $\sin(5\beta)+\sin(\beta)=1$ are the zeros of a fourth degree polynomial, hence can all be expressed in terms of radicals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this answer meaningfull but if you need this roots, here they are
$$
x_1=\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
x_2=-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{35}{24}-\frac{1}{24}
   \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{395+3
   \sqrt{1713}}-\frac{15}{8} \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}
$$
$$
x_3=-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{35}{24}-\frac{1}{24}
   \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{395+3
   \sqrt{1713}}-\frac{15}{8} \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}
$$
$$
x_4=-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{35}{24}-\frac{1}{24}
   \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{395+3
   \sqrt{1713}}+\frac{15}{8} \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}
$$
$$
x_5=-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{35}{24}-\frac{1}{24}
   \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{395+3
   \sqrt{1713}}+\frac{15}{8} \sqrt{\frac{3}{35+2 \sqrt[3]{3160-24 \sqrt{1713}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{395+3 \sqrt{1713}}}}}
$$
Numerical values
$$
x_1=0.500000000000000000000000000000,
$$
$$
x_2=-0.821076869248865871679368938530-0.147733318623280702329856547465i,
$$
$$
x_3=-0.821076869248865871679368938530+0.147733318623280702329856547465i,
$$
$$
x_4=0.188285649881385672907404476142,
$$
$$
x_5=0.953868088616346070451333400918
$$
The respecitive angles $\beta=\arcsin(x)$ in radians are
$$
\beta_1=0.523598775598298873077107230547,
$$
$$
\beta_2=-0.923163176894719154945644411954-0.242491674789456740938340067472i,
$$
$$
\beta_3=-0.923163176894719154945644411954+0.242491674789456740938340067472i,
$$
$$
\beta_4=0.189416282605918466874902490444,
$$
$$
\beta_5=1.26586671937652178290413890330
$$
The areas of domains $CGH$, $HBF$ are given by the formulas
$$
S_{CGH}=3 \beta -\frac{1}{2} \sin (6 \beta )-\frac{1}{2} \beta  \sec ^2(2 \beta )-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sec ^2(2 \beta )-1}-\frac{\pi }{4}+1
$$
$$
S_{HBF}=\beta  \sec ^2(2 \beta )-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\sec ^2(2 \beta )-1}
$$
The respecitve numericals values for $CGH$ are
$$
S_{CGH,1}=-0.127824791583588083302276786026,
$$
$$
S_{CGH,2}=-3.99683686501392644407946565939-0.54938014174210294554189328651i,
$$
$$
S_{CGH,3}=-3.99683686501392644407946565939+0.54938014174210294554189328651i,
$$
$$
S_{CGH,4}=0.0205233661564834188106917673615,
$$
$$
S_{CGH,5}=2.23756796644691039586047775118
$$
for $HFB$ are
$$
S_{HFB,1}=1.22836969860875684554470575143,
$$
$$
S_{HFB,2}=0.15747480940566025178679372899+3.71420167984539571383021593893i,
$$
$$
S_{HFB,3}=0.15747480940566025178679372899-3.71420167984539571383021593893i,
$$
$$
S_{HFB,4}=0.0203997399628726939700469522529,
$$
$$
S_{HFB,5}=1.53450150774254892235003332376
$$
Computations were made via Mathematica $8$ with $30$ digit precision.

Comment: Really quite huge radical results. I did not expect to see such complex results.  What about Areas . Is it possible to show how they are near each other via using Mathematica 8. Pity that I do not have mathematica 8. Thanks a lot for help and answer. very appreciated

Comment: Just give the formulas for this areas, i will compute them and extend the answer

Comment: They are in my question. I calculated for P≈0.188286. Is not it clear for you?

Comment: As far as I understand they are $$1-\left(\frac{\beta x^2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(6\beta)+\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-3\beta\right)\right)$$ and $$\beta x^2-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{2}$$ Right?

Comment: Yes. Correct results

Comment: Ok, I will compute them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great contribution. Seems 30 digit results are near my 6 digit results for fourth root. The areas are near each other about 3 digits after point. Really I was excited and expected to find more digits are equal.thanks again for your helps

Comment: I think this question is answered :)

Comment: yes . most of my wonders solved. Now I wonder if we accept the areas equal how much digits $\pi$ will correct. But 3 digits of equal areas not so much I expected. I do not know that the  assumption of equal areas how many correct digits of $\pi$ will offer me . I do not expect many digits. But if I find how many correct digits I can get, I will update my question. Thanks a lot again for your contribution to my research.

Comment: Not at all!${}$

Comment: Never stop to think more. :)

Comment: Impressive, but I am confused. My understanding is if a quartic equation has four real roots, its resolvent cubic has three positive real roots and so is casus irreducibilis -- the cube root radicands are complex. So how are all the radicals real for four roots here?